# How to set fixed headers to the feign client instead of setting on request level

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

I am using feign client for inter-service communication; question is I am able to send the method/request headers on request level meaning ex:

```
@FeignClient(name = "product-service", url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
public interface ProductClient {

    @GetMapping("/posts")
    List<PostDTO> fetchPosts(@RequestHeaders....);

    @GetMapping("/posts/{id}")
    List<PostDTO> fetchPostsById(@RequestHeaders...., @PathVariable("id")int id);
```

But as header is fixed, instead of sending the same value to each request; can we set it on class level; I tried below; it is not working

```
@FeignClient(name = "product-service", url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
@Headers({
        "X-Ping: {token}"
})
public interface ProductClient {

    @GetMapping("/posts")
    List<PostDTO> fetchPosts(@RequestHeaders....);

    @GetMapping("/posts/{id}")
    List<PostDTO> fetchPostsById(@RequestHeaders...., @PathVariable("id")int id);
```

Correct me with the API or an example.

Answer (score 10):

You can create an interceptor that'd inject headers in all requests as below:

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
  return requestTemplate -> {
      requestTemplate.header("user", username);
      requestTemplate.header("password", password);
      requestTemplate.header("Accept", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());
  };
}
```

Also it provides a way to set interceptor using property files as below:

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        requestInterceptors:
          com.baeldung.cloud.openfeign.JSONPlaceHolderInterceptor
```

> we can create the configuration with default as the client name to configure all @FeignClient objects, or we can declare the feign client name for a configuration

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-openfeign

EDIT:
Another way is to set headers in yml as below:

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        defaultRequestHeaders:
          Authorization:
            - Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
          SomeOtherHeader:
            - Value1
            - Value2
```

Answer (score 1):

we have used below for kotlin to make sure we add proper headers to all the request sent :

Feign client with configuration setup

```
@FeignClient(name = "YourClient", url = "\${base-url}", configuration = [FeignHeaderConfiguration::class])
interface YourClient
```

Header configuration

```
@Configuration
class FeignHeaderConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun clientHeaderInterceptor(): ClientHeaderInterceptor {
        return ClientHeaderInterceptor()
    }
}
```

and interceptor where we added the header

```
class ClientHeaderInterceptor : RequestInterceptor {
    override fun apply(requestTemplate: RequestTemplate) {
       requestTemplate.header("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    }
}
```